# Elki plot cluster points directly from java

Tags: plot, cluster-analysis, elki

Is it possible to plot Elki's cluster results to a graph directly using Elki? I don't see any test cases http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/browser/elki/elki/src/test/java#de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki which do this. I know it's possible to plot points using java but I wanted to do that using Elki.

Comment: Graph? As in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics) ? How would you do a unit test for graphics (assuming you meant a bitmap)?

Comment: I just thought that maybe there would be some test case for the minigui which plot out the clustering results in a graph. I just wanted to know how to generate graphs using Elki directly through java.

Comment: Graph != graphic... and again: how would the test know it worked? Pixel per pixel comparison, and hoping it doesn't depend on your JDK?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse good point. I just wanted to plot the results from the clustering algorithm so that I can see what it produces. I'm just finding it hard to find some examples of code that does this so I was looking at the unit tests. I did look at the ExportVisualizations class but I dont know how to set the VisualizerParameterizer class so that I can use it. Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used it from Java. From command line it just works.

Comment: @RegUser did you manage to solve your problem and plot the result? I have the same problem with plotting the ClusterResult!

Comment: @Paul I actually paused and didnt complete it.. other things got my attention. Let me know how you get on :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the class `ExportVisualizations` to generate SVG plots.

http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/browser/elki/addons/batikvis/src/main/java/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/visualization/ExportVisualizations.java

Visualizations are in the "addon/batikvis" module, because of the Apache Batik dependency.

To *display* the SVG file, use Apache Batik.

Comment: I have looked at the code but how can I set the VisualizerParameterizer class with just the default settings so that I can use the ExportVisualisation? Is there a class which uses ExportVisualisations so that I can see how it works and try to get it working? The VisualizerParameterizer has many parameters I dont know what to initialise them with.

Comment: The helper class `ClassGenericsUtil.parameterizeOrAbort` will instantiate any parameterizable object in ELKI with default values; the same way as done by the command line and MiniGUI. This is necessary to have auto-generated UIs. Java does not allow specifying defaults for parameters; you need to copy&paste the constructors.
ExportVisualizations is used the very same way: dynamically discovered, parameterized, and executed as `ResultHandler`.

Comment: So I created a "VisualizerParameterizer" object using "ClassGenericsUtil.parameterizeOrAbort". I tried to use "ExportVisualizations" but the constructor is protected so I decided to extend the ExportVisualizations class and call "exportVisualizations.processNewResult(result.getHierarchy(), result);"  but I get the error "No database reachable from de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.result.ResultHierarchy@53f48368" is this because "result.getHierarchy()" elements are null? I do have multiple clusters and I'm using DBSCAN

Comment: where result is of type "Clustering<Model>", it is the value returned after calling dbscan.run(db)

Comment: The constructor can probably be made public. But yes, it expects results to be connected to a database (more precisely, to a hierarchy of results). Sorry, I *never* used that part from pure Java. I just do not need that, I use the command line or MiniGUI. It is open source. You can make the constructor "public".

Comment: So when you cluster, you cluster from a database (which is what I'm doing) but there is no hierarchy of results. When I call result.getHierarchy() all i get is a hierarchy with null elements. Why is this hierarchy empty shouldnt it be  populated? How could I populate it?

Comment: db.getHierarchy() seems to be producing some svg plots but I can open the svg files.. tried multiple apps but there is something wrong

Comment: I used: VisualizerParameterizer parameterizer = ClassGenericsUtil.parameterizeOrAbort(VisualizerParameterizer.class, params);
        ExportVisualizations exportVisualizations = new MyExportVisualizations(new File("XX"), parameterizer, 500);
        exportVisualizations.processNewResult(db.getHierarchy(), result);

Comment: Again, "something wrong" is not precise, nor is "multiple apps". Also, why do you use a *ratio* of 500:1?

Comment: Good point. Sorry I was not precise, I hope that I'm precise now. I used DrawBerry on my Laptop to open the svg files. I just put 500 to see if it works. I changed it to 1:1 ratio, I realised its for the width of the plot. Now 4 plots (files) are exported, but only two of the files are actually graphs, the other two are empty, but the issue is that these plots have no axis I want to understand what plots are actually exported? if I can add axis to them? how these plots can be used? Thank you, I'm trying to find out used the debugger but any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It will try to export everything, but sometimes a visualization might not be available. The visualizers were changed substantially, and the export was not double-checked. These probably are a key visualization, but you do not have labels. Thus, it is empty. But the visualization is created anyway, because you could dynamically add a key later. etc. Please contribute improvements!

Comment: I have made the constructor public, but it is really easier to use the parameterizer (for ExportVisualizations already) because you need to find and instantiate all visualization factories you want to use otherwise.
The new version will also use much better file names. This will be in 0.7.0 final.